# Second CopyPicture in VBA fails with "Automation error"

Tags: vba, excel

So I am copying and pasting a bunch of data to another spreadsheet. I thought this last bit was going to be easy since I've done this a bunch of times in this script.

Except it fails. Here's part of my code:

```
ProdCK.Worksheets("CK week").Range("A11:AY28").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen
Worksheets("Prod.CK").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Prod.CK").Range("A1")

ProdCK.Worksheets("CK week").Range("I131:BO148").CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen
Worksheets("Prod.CK").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Prod.CK").Range("A22")
```

The first one works fine, but then the second one crashes on the CopyPicture operation. I've checked that a range is actually present by first storing that in a range, checking if the data is there in the "watch" screen and then calling CopyPicture on that, but nonetheless is still gives a

> 424 error Object required

Can anyone shine a light on this for me?

---

UPDATE:

The error is actually

> -2147417851 Automation error The server threw an exception

My error handling code had a bug which turned the automation error into the Object required error. What is also interesting is that the error does not happen when I use a visible Excel.Application in this Sub. The only difference between my visible and invisible settings are `Visible = True` and `ScreenUpdating = True`.

Comment: Are those 4 statements together in your code, i.e. no other statements between them?

Comment: Yes, they are come directly after each other. There are other subs in which I do the exact same thing, and then it does work.

Comment: And does "I've checked that a range is actually present by first storing that in a range ... and then calling CopyPicture on that" mean you tried inserting a line such as `Dim rng As Range : Set rng = ProdCK.Worksheets("CK week").Range("I131:BO148") : rng.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen` and it still crashed on the `rng.CopyPicture` part, not the `Set rng = ...` part?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did.

Comment: What is the ProdCK object equal to?

Comment: OK - very weird.  In `rng.CopyPicture` the only object is `rng` and that is definitely valid.  Wait ... do you have any `On Error Resume Next` statements?  Or `On Error GoTo ...` statements?

Comment: @garbb ProdCK is a Workbook.

Comment: @YowE3K on error I go to the bottom of the sub to close the workbooks. Which is what it does, and then it reraises the error to the calling sub which will also close its things and give a popup message.

Comment: If you have an `On Error GoTo bottom_of_sub` then you shouldn't be seeing an error, unless you have at some point incorrectly gone back into your code while still in error handling mode.  Or are you saying that the `424 error Object required` is what your own popup message is displaying after the error handling is finished?

Comment: @YowE3K No, at the bottom of the sub I raise the error again and then the calling sub will print out the error info as a debug message and give a popup to the user. So I see the error in the debug log. And when I go through it step by step I can see that it crashes on the CopyPicture.

Comment: Temporarily put an `On Error GoTo 0` just before the line that is causing the issue - just to confirm that it is actually an object required error.  (Maybe there is something in your error handling that causes the error message that gets displayed to **always** say "object required" irrespective of the actual error, so I just want to discard that as a possible reason.)

Comment: @YowE3K I've seen this process throw all sorts of errors and they have always matched with the problem, but I checked and I can confirm that it is indeed the error. But in the process I've figured out that the error does not happen if I use a visible Excel application.
I open a different Excel application to deal with workbooks and the only settings that are different are that `Visible = True` and `ScreenUpdating = True`.
This is becoming weirder.

Comment: That is definitely getting weirder. FWIW, I just tried doing two `CopyPicture` statements on ranges in a sheet in a workbook in an invisible, non-screen-updating, instance of Excel and no errors occurred.  I think you are just going to have to try and cut down your code until you get a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can play with. On the way to achieving that MCVE, you may well find the answer to the issue yourself. (Judging by your replies you seem to have a good understanding of what you are doing.) If you do, please post a "self-answer" so we know what the issue was.

Comment: @YowE3K yeah, since this issue doesn't occur anywhere else in similar code I don't know if I can make an MCVE. At least with the visible Excel thing there is something to play around with. I'm going to try that tomorrow.
Thank you for your comments!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160591/discussion-between-bob-and-yowe3k).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to figure out why but currently I just set `App.Visible = True` before these two statements and set it back to `App.Visible = False` afterwards. This gets things working.

I really dislike it though.